# How to make connection between android emulator(non samsung android phone) and Gear emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am trying to connect my android phone to test gear app, i have followed the steps given in the link - How to make connection between android emulator and Gear emulator, However i am still not able to connect. Please provide a solution.